# How to plot two functions?

Tags: plotting, functions

```
a[x_,y_]:=x^3+y^2;
b[x_,y_]:=x^2+y^3;
```

I want to plot a[x,y] in x axis and b[x,y] in y axis for different values of x and y say, we fix y=1 and x goes from 1 to 10.

Comment: `a = #1^3 + #2^2&;` shorter : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `ParametricPlot`

```
a[x_, y_] := x^3 + y^2;
b[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^3;
ParametricPlot[{a[x, 1], b[x, 1]}, {x, 1, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Haha almost at the same time, I think I beat you by a few seconds! (+1)

Comment: Congratulation ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`With`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) to give a local value for `y` and [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) for the plot.

```
a[x_,y_]:=x^3+y^2;
b[x_,y_]:=x^2+y^3;

With[
   {y=1},
   ParametricPlot[
      { a[x,y], b[x,y] }
      , {x, 1, 10}
      , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
      , AspectRatio -> 1
   ]
]
```

[image]